# How to save Google Maps V3 distance result to MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, google-maps

(and sorry in advance for this being such a basic question at its core)

I have a MySQL database with location info, and a PHP script that can put a new, user-submitted location into the database. I want to then (immediately) find the distances between the newly-submitted location and a subset of the existing locations in the database using a Google Maps directions request, and *store* these distances in the database.

I can select the locations subset via PHP and use JavaScript to fetch the distance data with Google Maps, but how do I then transfer these JavaScript variables to my database? -What's the best way to save a group of JavaScript variables as separate entries in a MySQL database?

Thanks for your help!

Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the distances properly loaded into variables in your JS code, then you can make an XmlHttpRequest to send them to your server where a PHP script will put them into the database. The pseudo-code would be something like this:

JS:

```
function storeDistance(pointId1, pointId2, distance) {
  var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/savedistance.php", true);
  xhr.send("pid1=" + pointId1 + "&pid2=" + pointId2 + "&distance=" + distance);
}
```

PHP:

```
$pointId1 = $_POST['pid1'];
$pointId2 = $_POST['pid2'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
mysql_query("insert into distances values ($pointId1, $pointId2, $distance)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a project where I encountered the same problem. If it is between two points A and B, you can refer to
  http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

If the number of points

```
editroutes = JSON.parse(editroutes);
origin = editroutes.ag.origin;
destination = editroutes.ag.destination;
var ag = editroutes.ag.waypoints;

for(i=0;i<ag.length;i++){
    if(typeof ag[i].location == 'object'){
        waypoints.push({location:new google.maps.LatLng(ag[i].location.Ia, ag[i].location.Ja),stopover:ag[i].stopover});
    }else if(typeof ag[i].location == 'string'){
        waypoints.push({location:ag[i].location,stopover:ag[i].stopover});
    }
}

avoidHighways =  editroutes.ag.avoidHighways;
avoidTolls = editroutes.ag.avoidTolls;
var request = {
       origin: origin,
       destination: destination,
       waypoints: waypoints,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
       optimizeWaypoints: false,
       avoidHighways: avoidHighways,
       avoidTolls: avoidTolls
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```